# Why is sum $\cot^{-1}(n^2+n+1)$ equal to $\cot^{-1}\left(\frac1{m+1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can u Please Explain This sum result :
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \cot^{-1} (n^2+n+1) = \cot^{-1} \left(\frac1{m+1}\right)$$

Comment: Please provide context including your reasoning and attempts to amswer the question.

Comment: This is (essentially) problem A3 from the 1986 Putnam: https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol863.html

Answer (score 3):

Recall (or prove) the subtraction law for tangent. We have
$$\tan(x-y)=\frac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos(x-y)}=\frac{\sin x\cos y -\cos x\sin y}{\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y} =\frac{\tan x-\tan   y}{1+\tan x\tan y}. 
 \tag{1} $$.

Now use this to calculate $\cot^{-1} (1/(k+1))-\cot^{-1}(1/k))$. Taking the tangent, we get by (1), using $x=k+1$ and $y=k$, that
$$\tan(\tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k))=1/(k^2+k+1).$$
Thus
$$\cot^{-1}(k^2+k+1)=\cot^{-1}(1/(k+1))-\cot^{-1} (k).\tag{2}$$
Now add from $k=0$ to $m$. Using (2) and telescoping we get the desired result.